# Why my spline function don't work?

Tags: vba

i`m have some problems with the spline function that find in net..dias(days) and taxas(rate) are two arrays of my spreadsheet, and T is the number of days that I want know the respective rate..When I used this function setting the array inside the function it works well...but using the arrays of spreadsheet the VBA  sad me that can;t find the project or the library..someone can help me? Thanks

```
 Function NDF6(T, dias, taxas)
 Dim x As Variant
 x = T
 Dim xin() As Variant
 Dim yin() As Variant
 Dim input_count As Integer
 Dim output_count As Integer
 input_count = dias.Count
 output_count = taxas.Count

ReDim xin(input_count)
ReDim yin(output_count)
Dim c As Integer
For c = 1 To input_count
  xin(c) = dias(c)
  yin(c) = taxas(c)
Next c

          'values are populated

  Dim n As Integer 'n=input_count
 Dim i, k As Integer 'these are loop counting integers
 Dim p, qn, sig, un As Variant
 Dim u() As Variant
 ReDim u(input_count - 1) As Variant
 Dim yt() As Variant 'these are the 2nd deriv values
 ReDim yt(output_count - 1) As Variant
 Dim y As Double

  n = input_count
  yt(1) = 0
  u(1) = 0
 For i = 2 To n - 1
 sig = (xin(i) - xin(i - 1)) / (xin(i + 1) - xin(i - 1))
 p = sig * yt(i - 1) + 2
 yt(i) = (sig - 1) / p
  u(i) = (yin(i + 1) - yin(i)) / (xin(i + 1) - xin(i)) - (yin(i) - yin(i - 1)) / (xin(i) - xin(i _  - 1))
  u(i) = (6 * u(i) / (xin(i + 1) - xin(i - 1)) - sig * u(i - 1)) / p

  Next i

  qn = 0
  un = 0
  yt(n) = (un - qn * u(n - 1)) / (qn * yt(n - 1) + 1)
  For k = n - 1 To 1 Step -1
    yt(k) = yt(k) * yt(k + 1) + u(k)
  Next k

  'now eval spline at one point

   Dim klo, khi As Integer
   Dim h, b, a As Single
   ' first find correct interval
   klo = 1
   khi = n
   Do
    k = khi - klo
    If xin(k) > x Then
      khi = k
    Else
      klo = k
   End If
   k = khi - klo
   Loop While k > 1
   h = xin(khi) - xin(klo)
    a = (xin(khi) - x) / h
   b = (x - xin(klo)) / h
   y = a * yin(klo) + b * yin(khi) + ((a ^ 3 - a) * yt(klo) + (b ^ 3 - b) * yt(khi)) * (h ^ 2) / _ 6

    NDF6 = y

    End Function
```

Comment: Make sure `input_count = output_count` as `x()` and `y()` need to have the same dimensions.

Comment: It would be best to try your function first in a *SUB* and step by step check what is causing the error. That way you can isolate the issue. You might even be able to solve it yourself in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my code:

[image: Excel]

The sheet is calculated with:

```
Public Sub TestSpline()

    Dim x() As Variant, y() As Variant, ypp() As Variant
    Dim xe() As Variant, ye() As Variant

    x = [B2].Resize(13, 1).Value
    y = [C2].Resize(13, 1).Value
    xe = [N2].Resize(49, 1).Value

    CalculateYpp x, y, ypp
    CalculatePoints x, y, ypp, xe, ye

    [O2].Resize(49, 1).Value = ye

End Sub
```

and the *Cubic Spline* calculation is done with:

```
Public Sub CalculateYpp(ByRef x() As Variant, ByRef y() As Variant, ByRef ypp() As Variant, Optional dydx_1 As Variant = vbNullString, Optional dydx_N As Variant = vbNullString)

    Dim N As Integer, Z As Integer
    'calculate 2nd derivatives
    N = UBound(x, 1): Z = UBound(y, 2)
    ReDim ypp(1 To N, 1 To Z)

    Dim u() As Variant
    ReDim u(1 To N, 1 To Z)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Z
        If Not IsNumeric(dydx_1) Then
            ypp(1, i) = 0#
            u(1, i) = 0#
        Else
            ypp(1, i) = -0.5
            u(1, i) = 3# / (x(2, 1) - x(1, 1)) * ((y(2, i) - y(1, i)) / (x(2, 1) - x(1, 1)) - CDbl(dydx_1))
        End If

        Dim k As Integer
        Dim sig As Variant
        Dim P As Variant, hn As Variant, hi As Variant
        For k = 2 To N - 1 Step 1
            hi = x(k, 1) - x(k - 1, 1)
            hn = x(k + 1, 1) - x(k, 1)
            sig = hi / (hn + hi)
            P = sig * ypp(k - 1, 1) + 2#
            ypp(k, i) = (sig - 1#) / P
            If Abs(hn) > 0 And Abs(hi) > 0 Then
                u(k, i) = (6# * ((y(k + 1, i) - y(k, i)) / hn - (y(k, i) - y(k - 1, i)) / hi) _
                        / (hn + hi) - sig * u(k - 1, i)) / P
            ElseIf Abs(hi) > 0 Then
                u(k, i) = (6# * (-(y(k, i) - y(k - 1, i)) / hi) / (hn + hi) - sig * u(k - 1, i)) / P
            ElseIf Abs(hn) > 0 Then
                u(k, i) = (6# * ((y(k + 1, i) - y(k, i)) / hn) / (hn + hi) - sig * u(k - 1, i)) / P
            Else
                u(k, i) = -sig * u(k - 1, i) / P
            End If
        Next k
        Dim qn As Variant
        If Not IsNumeric(dydx_N) Then
            qn = 0#
            u(N, i) = 0#
        Else
            qn = 0.5
            u(N, i) = 3# / (x(N, 1) - x(N - 1, 1)) * (CDbl(dydx_N) - (y(N, i) - y(N - 1, i)) / _
                            (x(N, 1) - x(N - 1, 1)))
        End If
        ypp(N, i) = (u(N, i) - qn * u(N - 1, i)) / (qn * ypp(N - 1, i) + 1#)
        For k = N - 1 To 1 Step -1
            ypp(k, i) = ypp(k, i) * ypp(k + 1, i) + u(k, i)
        Next k

    Next i 'Next Column

End Sub

Public Function IndexOf(ByRef x() As Variant, ByVal x_value As Variant) As Integer
    Dim K1 As Integer, K2 As Integer, k As Integer, N As Integer
    N = UBound(x, 1)
    'Do bisection to find index of xi()
    K1 = 1
    K2 = N
    Do While (K2 - K1) > 1
        k = (K1 + K2) / 2
        If (x(K1, 1) - x_value) * (x(k, 1) - x_value) <= 0 Then
            K2 = k
        Else
            K1 = k
        End If
    Loop
    k = K1
    If k > N - 1 Then k = N - 1

    IndexOf = k
End Function

Public Sub CalculatePoints(ByRef x() As Variant, ByRef y() As Variant, ByRef ypp() As Variant, ByRef xe() As Variant, ByRef ye() As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer, k As Integer, K1 As Integer
    Dim N As Integer, Z As Integer
    N = UBound(xe, 1): Z = UBound(y, 2)
    ReDim ye(1 To N, 1 To Z)

    Dim x1 As Variant, y1 As Variant, y1pp As Variant
    Dim x2 As Variant, y2 As Variant, y2pp As Variant
    Dim A As Variant, b As Variant, h As Variant, C As Variant, D As Variant

    For i = 1 To Z
        For k = 1 To N
            K1 = IndexOf(x, xe(k, 1))
            x1 = x(K1, 1)
            x2 = x(K1 + 1, 1)
            y1 = y(K1, i)
            y2 = y(K1 + 1, i)
            y1pp = ypp(K1, i)
            y2pp = ypp(K1 + 1, i)
            h = x2 - x1
            A = (x2 - xe(k, 1)) / h
            b = (xe(k, 1) - x1) / h
            C = (A * A * A - A) * h ^ 2 / 6#
            D = (b * b * b - b) * h ^ 2 / 6#

            ye(k, i) = y1 * A + y2 * b + y1pp * C + y2pp * D
        Next k
    Next i
End Sub
```

It would even work for multiple columns for `y` and `ye`.

Comment: on really I don't try..I had got the code in net..but I did some changes..now I try use the original code and it work I only have to remove some references tools..now I have another problem if you could see the topic: the result of my function when I call a spline function gives wrong values, I will be grateful